# How do I run commands on the same and different terminals with child_process?

Tags: node.js, electron, ros, child-process

I want to perform multiple terminal events with one button. But after running the **roscore** command in one terminal, I must run two more commands in another terminal before that terminal closes (these two commands have to work in the same terminal). How is this possible?

```js
exec('cd ~/catkin_ws', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                if (error.signal == 'SIGTERM') {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(stderr);
                }
            } else {
                console.log(stdout);
                exec('pwd', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if (error) {
                        if (error.signal == 'SIGTERM') {
                            console.log(error);
                        } else {
                            console.log(stderr);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log(stdout);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

For example, I am trying to make the **pwd** output above be / home / famara / catkin_ws. But I get the result of / home / famara.

I have not tried many ways. I have also read [this page](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) but could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you do something like this. In a simpler way.

`cd ~` returns you to your user account's home folder.

`pwd` It prints the current directory name with the complete path starting from root (/)

```
exec('cd ~/catkin_ws && pwd', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
 if (error) {
  if (error.signal == 'SIGTERM') {
   console.log(error);
  } else {
   console.log(stderr);
  }
 } else {
  console.log(stdout);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I didn't know that && syntax was used like this. Mostly the problem is solved. The code is working. The second one just doesn't work before the first terminal closes. How can I operate the second terminal without stopping the first terminal?